# Use scope variable in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to use a $scope variable within the ng-repeat attribut, like so :

```
<div class="userOpinion" ng-if="usersOpinions.length != 0" ng-repeat="userOpinion in {{usersOpinion}}">
```

But it doesnt seem to work, {{usersOpinion}} remains non-interpreted... How could I manage to make it work?

The Idea is to dynamically change {{usersOpinion}} when clicking on button.

Thanks

Comment: Change `ng-repeat="userOpinion in {{usersOpinion}}` to `ng-repeat="userOpinion in usersOpinion` and make sure that there is usersOpinion initialize inside controller or using `ng-init`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ng-repeat="userOpinion in {{usersOpinion}}"` ,change it to `ng-repeat="userOpinion in usersOpinions`.

You should use like

```
<div class="userOpinion" ng-if="usersOpinions.length != 0" ng-repeat="userOpinion in usersOpinions">{{userOpinion}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to remove the curly brackets. The ng-repeat is interpreted as code.

```
<div class="userOpinion" ng-if="usersOpinions.length != 0" ng-repeat="userOpinion in usersOpinion">
```

The curly brackets tells angular that it should transform the variable into a string before outputting it.

Comment: I agree on that but what I want is to dynamically change the array it will go through. How can I manage to change the array in iterate on click on button ?

Comment: You can have a variable in $scope where you point to the array you want to iterate through `ng-repeat="userOpinion in tempArray"` and set `$scope.tempArray = $scope.usersOpinion` in the controller

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it dynamically you need to add ng-click to div tag, something like this

```
  <div class="userOpinion" ng-if="usersOpinions.length != 0" ng-repeat="userOpinion in usersOpinion" ng-click="changeOpinion($index)">
    {{userOpinion}}
  </div>
```

and add function to scope

```
$scope.changeOpinion = function (index) {
    $scope.usersOpinion[index] += '1';
}
```

no you can do whaterver you want with value of that opinion, here is the whole code with both simple array of opinions and objects http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/9513/

Answer (score 0):

if I'm understand your question, you can try this

```js
var autoDrops = angular.module('autoDrops', []);
autoDrops.controller('DropsController', function($scope) {
  $scope.usersOpinion = [];

  $scope.datas = [{
    "name": "item01"
  }, {
    "name": "item02"
  }, {
    "name": "item03"
  }, {
    "name": "item04"
  }, {
    "name": "item05"
  }, {
    "name": "item06"
  }];
  $scope.datas1 = [{
    "name": "item11"
  }, {
    "name": "item12"
  }, {
    "name": "item13"
  }, {
    "name": "item14"
  }, {
    "name": "item15"
  }, {
    "name": "item16"
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="autoDrops" ng-controller="DropsController">
  <button ng-click="usersOpinion = datas">
    data
  </button>
  <button ng-click="usersOpinion = datas1">
    datas1
  </button>
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="elem in usersOpinion">
      {{elem}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```